# is it possible to have Spring configuration relying only on annotations apart from being spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm new in Spring applications, and see the big difference between configurations in springBoot and spring. So my questin is: apart from spring-boot, is there a way to setup a proper spring application(with web mvc, security, aop, ...), without any xml config file (ie : config relying only on annotations).

Comment: yes, it's possible to create spring boot annotations based application without any xml configurations files.

Comment: One big  idea with Spring Boot is to be able to set up an app with zero xml config files. So i know that it is possible with it. But my question is can we do the same with Spring alone.(not with Spring Boot).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to do this in Spring. Spring Boot is after all an enhanced, autoconfigured Spring (with other cool features). That means that everything there is in Spring Boot should be achievable in Spring as well, but you would have do a bit/a lot of Your own extra work.

Moving straight to the point, in order to achieve what you want, you would need to undertake the following steps:

1. Create a class, which will store all the configuration (basically the properties you would store in the xml file) - let's call it AppConfig.class
2. Annotate the AppConfig.class with @Configuration - this will inform Spring that this class is the source of configuration;
3. Annotate the AppConfig.class with @ComponentScan("com.app") - here, You need to provide a package, from which Spring has to start component scanning in order to find Beans to be registered in Spring Container. Important note is, that it will scan the package and it's subpackages, so you would mostly want to provide here the top level package;
4. If you need some data to be injected into your beans, you would want to use the @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties") - I have provided here the default value, which Spring Boot uses internally in case you want to inject some data into your beans at runtime. For this to work, you need to inject into AppConfig.class an Environment.class

To show it on the example:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.app")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    // it will help to pull the properties incorporated in the file you have provided in the @PropertySource annotation
    private Environment environment;

//inject it
    public AppConfig(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

// build your beans - the getProperty method accepts the key from application.properties
// file and return a value as a String. You can provide additional arguments to convert 
//the value and a default value if the property is not found
    @Bean
    public Product product() {
       
        return new Product(
                environment.getProperty("product.name", "XXX"),
                environment.getProperty("product.price", BigDecimal.class, BigDecimal.ZERO),
                environment.getProperty("product.quantity", Integer.class, 10)
        );
    }

}
```

I hope that it helps

Comment: Thank you for this response that is very clear, and detailed. But, in the same idea (no xml config file), how to setup a working web MVC application with a full-fledged seccurity service enabled?